# Is it possible to don't trigger checkbox when clicked on its label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, checkbox

Basically what I wan't to do is to make jQuery function that when it is clicked on the checkbox name I have prompt window to change checkbox name, but it is automatically check/uncheck checkbox itself. I need that Is it possible to don't trigger checkbox when clicked on its label?

P.S Hope it clear what i wrote :)

My markup is:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check">
  <label for="check1">Checklist One</label>
  <br>
  <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" checked>
  <label for="check2">Checklist two</label>
  <br>
  <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check">
  <label for="check3">Checklist 3</label>
</div> <!-- END OF CHECKBOX -->
```

Comment: Why don't you use a span tag instead of a label, give it an id and use this id as selector in jquery?

Comment: Don't write the `for` attribute. The `for` attribute on a label just links it to simulate a click on the element it's `for`. @nick78 - I would still advise using a label, as this would be semantically correct, over using a span

Comment: Change the name attribute of the `<input>` or change the text in the label element?

Comment: Sorted, Thank You All! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```js
$('label').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // here you can add your code to handle the rename
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check">
  <label for="check1">Checklist One</label>
  <br>
  <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" checked>
  <label for="check2">Checklist two</label>
  <br>
  <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check">
  <label for="check3">Checklist 3</label>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Willi, your answer looks great, but somehow checkbox itself, doesn't work. Maybe there is something wrong somewhere else in my code.

Comment: that´s strange i can klick the checkboxes. what browser are you using ?

Comment: Yeah I see everything works great on code snippet you wrote, but when I change my code it doesn't work. I use Chrome.

Comment: mayde you habe some code that block´s that behavior ?

Comment: Yes Willi my styling of checkbox itself caused this behavior! Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Remove for attribute from label

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check">
    <label>Checklist One</label>
    <br>
    <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" checked>
    <label>Checklist two</label>
    <br>
    <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check">
    <label>Checklist 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: When I remove for attribute, checklist itself doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is the following:

```
// binding the anonymous function of the on() method
// as the 'click' event-handler, passing the event to
// that anonymous function:
$('label').on('click', function (e) {
  // preventing the default action of the
  // <label> element:
  e.preventDefault();

  // selecting the appropriate <input> element using
  // the htmlFor property of the <label>:      
  $('#' + this.htmlFor)
    // updating the name property (not the attribute)
    // of the <input> using the anonymous function of
    // of the prop() method:
    .prop('name', function(i,oldName) {
      // i: the first argument, the index of the
      // current element in the collection,
      // oldName: the current value of the property
      // we're working with.

    // presenting a prompt to the user, informing them of the
    // current name, and asking if they wish to change it;
    // if they should enter a new name that new name is returned
    // to the variable, otherwise if they click cancel null
    // is returned:
    var newName = prompt("Do you want to change the name from " + oldName + '?');
    // here we check for a newName existing (so a new name was entered)
    // if it was we return that newName, otherwise we return the oldName:
    return newName ? newName : oldName;
  });

});
```

```js
$('label').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#' + this.htmlFor).prop('name', function(i, oldName) {
    var newName = prompt("Do you want to change the name from " + oldName + '?');
    return newName ? newName : oldName;
  });

});
```

```css
label::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check">
  <label for="check1">Checklist One</label>
  <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" checked>
  <label for="check2">Checklist two</label>
  <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check">
  <label for="check3">Checklist 3</label>
</div>
```

This is, of course, possible without jQuery using the native DOM:

```
// using a named function to handle the functionality,
// passing in the relevant element, the event and
// name of the property to change:
function updateProperty(el, event, property) {
  // cancelling the default behaviour:
  event.preventDefault();

  // finding the relevant <input> element using
  // the <label> element's htmlFor property:
  var input = document.getElementById(el.htmlFor),

    // retrieving the current property-value:
    oldVal = input[property],

    // asking the user if they want to update the
    // relevant property from the existing value:
    newVal = prompt("Do you want to update the " + property + " from '" + oldVal + "'?");

  // if they enter a new value that wil be stored as
  // as a String in the newVal variable and will
  // return a truthy result, and will set the
  // relevant property to the newVal, otherwise if
  // no new value was entered the newVal will 
  // evaluate to false, and the oldVal will be set as
  // the property-value:
  input[property] = newVal ? newVal : oldVal;

}

// converting the result of document.querySelectorAll() into
// an Array, using Array.from(), and iterating over that Array
// with Array.prototype.forEach():
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('label')).forEach(function(label) {
  // 'label' the first (only) argument is a reference to the
  // Array-element of the Array over which we're iterating.

  // binding the anonymous functiona s the 'click'
  // event-handler:
  label.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // 'e' is the event object.

    // here we call the function, and pass
    // arguments to that function:
    // 'this' : the <label> element that
    // received/initiated the event,
    // 'e' : the event itself,
    // 'name' : the property we wish to
    // update within the called function.
    updateProperty(this, e, 'name');
  });
});
```

```js
function updateProperty(el, event, property) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var input = document.getElementById(el.htmlFor),
    oldVal = input[property],
    newVal = prompt("Do you want to update the " + property + " from '" + oldVal + "'?");
  input[property] = newVal ? newVal : oldVal;

}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('label')).forEach(function(label) {
  label.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    updateProperty(this, e, 'name');
  });
});
```

```css
label::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
  <input id="check1" type="checkbox" name="check">
  <label for="check1">Checklist One</label>
  <input id="check2" type="checkbox" name="check" checked>
  <label for="check2">Checklist two</label>
  <input id="check3" type="checkbox" name="check">
  <label for="check3">Checklist 3</label>
</div>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/conditional_operator).
  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`HTMLLabelElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement).
  - [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop).